# Angularstrap Modal hides the vertical browser scrollbar

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-strap

I'm testing modal window of angular strap and something unwanted happens. In a large document while the modal is visible the browser scrollbar disappears. Then, when you close the modal, the browser scrollbar is displayed again and the document collapses a bit.

I was looking at the developer tools by an hour, but I can not find the cause.

It's annoying when the document collapses.

How I can prevent that scrollbar be invisible?

### HTML

```
<button data-animation="am-fade-and-scale" bs-modal="modal">
  Open Modal
</button>
```

### Controller

```
var app = angular.module('Test', ['ngAnimate', 'mgcrea.ngStrap']);

app.controller('ModalCtrl', 
  function($scope){
    $scope.modal = {
      "title" : "ModalTitle",
      "content" : "Modal content"
    };
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/yKZSnn?p=preview

### TESTED ON Windows 8.1

```
      Chrome 36, Firefox 31, Opera 24 - Same results.
      Safari 5.1.7 - Worst results, the overlayer still visible.
```

Comment: With what browser and OS are you experimenting this issue?

Comment: Yes, to get a large document and get scrollbar visible.

Comment: Yeah got it now, lets check it again.

Comment: Posted the solution, but why do you want the scroll bar to be visible as there is an overlay.

Comment: It's annoying when the document collapses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For modal the overflow is set to hidden.

You can set the overflow of body to auto to fix up the problem.

i.e `<body ng-controller="ModalCtrl" style="overflow: auto">`

Working Demo at http://plnkr.co/edit/DGb38NBp89Fl4Jhvvyx3?p=preview

Comment: if you have time, could explain why this happens?

Comment: I personally think there is no need of scroll bar, basically what you are doing is opening a popup i.e you are placing a div and giving it fixed position, so that it comes in front of every thing ( simulating a popup). In this scenario we don't need a scroll bar as everything is overlapped(hidden).
But in your case you explicitly want the scroll bar, so you have place your custom css as per your requirement.

Comment: i agree, but the page collapses when modal closes. i dislike this effect.

Comment: Thanks,  made my day. I was looking for solutions since many days but ignored as no one noticed that :D. Fixed it at last.

Answer (score 0):

The angular-modal-service adds class "modal-open" to your body tag when a modal page opens. It also adds padding-right: 15px to the body tag.

My solution to this is the following. Add this to your css and the page will not resize anymore during modal-open/modal-close.

```
body.modal-open {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```